# Compute $I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ac-b^2}{[a \sin(t)+ b \cos(t)]^2+[b \cos(t)+ c \sin(t)]^2}dt$

Tags: calculus

How do you compute

$$I = \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{ac-b^2}{[a \sin(t)+ b \cos(t)]^2+[b \cos(t)+ c \sin(t)]^2}dt = 2 \pi \ \mathrm{sign}(ac-b^2) $$

which comes up when computing the Poincare index? [Wolfram does not work](http://integrals.wolfram.com/index.jsp?expr=1%2F%28%28a%20Sin[x]%2BbCos[x]%29%5E2%2B%28bCos[x]%2BcSin[x]%29%5E2%29&random=false) out at all or give the steps :(

It comes from Courant/John volume 2 page 357-358

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kexM.png

Comment: I don't think your RHS is right, but you may find many details below.

Answer (score 3):

I will show you an overkill, but a useful one (at least, IMHO). If the quadratic form
$$ q(x,y) = A x^2 + 2B xy + C y^2 $$
associated with the matrix
$$ M_q=\begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ B & C\end{pmatrix}$$
is positive definite, i.e. (by Sylvester's criterion) $A>0$ and $AC-B^2>0$, then the integral
$$ I_q = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2}\exp\left(-q(x,y)\right)\,dx\,dy $$
is convergent and its value equals $\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{\det M_q}}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{AC-B^2}}$. The proof relies on the spectral theorem, Fubini's theorem and the fact that the determinant of $M_q$ is the product of its eigenvalues. What happens if we perform a change of variables, for instance if we switch to polar coordinates? We get:

$$ I_q = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho\exp\left(-\rho^2 q(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)\right)\,d\rho\,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{q(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)}.$$
In your case, the coefficients of the quadratic form $q$ are:
$$ A=2b^2,\qquad B=ba+bc,\qquad C=a^2+c^2.$$
Can you guess now what the value of your integral has to be? I got:

> $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{(a\sin t+b\cos t)^2+(b\cos t+c\sin t)^2}=\color{red}{\frac{2\pi}{\left|b\right|\cdot\left|a-c\right|}}$$
>   under the assumptions $b\neq 0$ and $a\neq c$.

Answer (score 2):

The response by Jack is undoubtedly the swift and elegant way to solve the problem, but presumes some linear algebra and multivariable calculus knowledge. For giggles, I thought I'd provide a solution accessible to first year calculus students based on the [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution). As Jack noted, the problem statement in its current form is incorrect.

Given $0<a^{2}+c^{2}\land0<b^{2}+d^{2}\land0<\left(ad-bc\right)^{2}$, we have

$$\begin{align}
I{\left(a,b,c,d\right)}
&:=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left[a\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+b\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]^{2}+\left[c\sin{\left(\theta\right)}+d\cos{\left(\theta\right)}\right]^{2}}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left[a^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}+2ab\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+b^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right]+\left[c^{2}\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}+2cd\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+d^{2}\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right]}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)\sin^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)\left(1-\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\theta\right)}\cos{\left(\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos^{2}{\left(\theta\right)}}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)+\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\left(\frac12+\frac12\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{2\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\left(1+\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}\right)}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(2\theta\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos{\left(2\theta\right)}}\\
&=\small{\int_{0}^{4\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}};~~~\small{\left[2\theta=\varphi\right]}\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&~~~~~+\int_{2\pi}^{4\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=2\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)+2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\varphi\right)}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}-a^{2}-c^{2}\right)\cos{\left(\varphi\right)}}\\
&=\small{2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\frac{\mathrm{d}\psi}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)-2\left(ab+cd\right)\sin{\left(\psi\right)}+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}\right)\cos{\left(\psi\right)}}};~~~\small{\left[\varphi-\pi=\psi\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)-2\left(ab+cd\right)\left(\frac{2t}{1+t^{2}}\right)+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}\right)\left(\frac{1-t^{2}}{1+t^{2}}\right)}\\
&~~~~~\times\,\frac{2}{1+t^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t;~~~\small{\left[\tan{\left(\frac{\psi}{2}\right)}=t\right]}\\
&=\small{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{4}{\left(a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}+d^{2}\right)\left(1+t^{2}\right)-2\left(ab+cd\right)\left(2t\right)+\left(a^{2}-b^{2}+c^{2}-d^{2}\right)\left(1-t^{2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)-2\left(ab+cd\right)t+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)t^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\\
&=\small{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\left(a^{2}+c^{2}\right)-2\left(ab+cd\right)\left(u+\frac{ab+cd}{b^{2}+d^{2}}\right)+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)\left(u+\frac{ab+cd}{b^{2}+d^{2}}\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u};~~~\small{\left[t=u+\frac{ab+cd}{b^{2}+d^{2}}\right]}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\frac{\left(ad-bc\right)^{2}}{b^{2}+d^{2}}+\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)u^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{2}{1+\frac{\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(ad-bc\right)^{2}}u^{2}}\cdot\frac{\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)}{\left(ad-bc\right)^{2}}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{2}{\left|ad-bc\right|}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{1+x^{2}};~~~\small{\left[\frac{\left(b^{2}+d^{2}\right)u}{\left|ad-bc\right|}=x\right]}\\
&=\frac{2\pi}{\left|ad-bc\right|}\\
\end{align}$$

Setting $d=b$, we find

$$I{\left(a,b,c,b\right)}=\frac{2\pi}{\left|a-c\right|\cdot\left|b\right|};~~~\small{b\neq0\land c\neq a}.\blacksquare$$

Comment: Hi, thank you! But I don't think it's mis-stated:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/5kexM.png
(Courant/John volume 2 page 357-8) If you replace $d = c$ and $c = b$ in your solution it gives the answer in this link right? Unfortunately I don't see why the other post works, I do know Gaussian integrals but... Thanks!

Comment: @Thramo The formula printed in Courant is incorrect. Try plugging in values for $a,b,c$ into Courant's formula and comparing the LHS and RHS numerically. For example, setting $a=2,b=1,c=-2$ the integral on the LHS will equal $-\frac52\pi$, but the expression on the RHS is $-2\pi$.

Comment: @Thramo: I agree. Even giants make mistakes, sometimes.